# Where to configure default Azure subscription region?

Tags: azure

Whenever I create an Azure resource the default region is set to US Central. Is there a way to configure the default region to be "Canada Central" instead?

Answer (score 8):

You did not mention if you want to set a default when using the Azure CLI.  Anyways, here's the command:

```
az config set defaults.location=canadacentral
```

Comment: Thanks, @CsharpRocks! Definitively this will come in handy. I actually was wondering if there is a default setting for when using the Azure Portal (e.g. so if you navigate to create a new App Service you see Central Canada).